# How do I map time series data with dates as columns using matplotlib in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm currently trying to plot some of the [CSSEGISandData/COVID-19](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19) data using matplotlib/Python. I have the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pandas import read_csv, to_datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot

if __name__ == '__main__':

    data_file = 'COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv'

    headers = [*read_csv(data_file, nrows=1)]

    global_fatal = read_csv(data_file, header=0, index_col=[0,1],
                            infer_datetime_format=1, parse_dates=True,
                            usecols=[c for c in headers if c != 'Long' and c != 'Lat'])

    columns = {}
    for col in global_fatal.columns:
        try:
            columns[col] = to_datetime(col, infer_datetime_format=True)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    global_fatal.rename(columns=columns, inplace=True)

    print(global_fatal.head())
    global_fatal.plot()
    pyplot.show()
```

But I get the dates as individual lines instead of the regions. I've tried to use other posts on here an tutorial to either remap the axis when I plot or change how they're pulled in via arguments to `pandas.read_csv`, but I can't get to seem to get the data to display sanely (with Countries as lines, time series/dates on the bottom/x-axis and number on the left/y-axis.

[image: Screenshot of plot from above code]

Here is the output from the `head()` function, so it looks like the data is getting imported correctly:

```
python3 charts.py
                               2020-01-22  2020-01-23  2020-01-24  ...  2020-03-23  2020-03-24  2020-03-25
Province/State Country/Region                                      ...                                    
NaN            Afghanistan              0           0           0  ...           1           1           2
               Albania                  0           0           0  ...           4           5           5
               Algeria                  0           0           0  ...          17          19          21
               Andorra                  0           0           0  ...           1           1           1
               Angola                   0           0           0  ...           0           0           0

[5 rows x 64 columns]
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to plot all 245 rows at once?

Comment: @pciunkiewicz Well I was going to see if I could limited to just a couple, but I figured the harder part was just getting the data to appear correct visually. But not that you mention it, I do need to select the countries in column 2 don't I?

Comment: I have posted an answer :)

Comment: The default `df.plot()` will plot **each column** as a **yvalue** with **index** as **x-axis**. I guess you may need to do `df.T.plot()`

Answer (score 0):

By default, calling the `DataFrame.plot()` method will result in each column being its own series on the plot. In order to get around this, you can simply transpose the dataframe so that the columns become the countries and your new x-axis is the date:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('covid19-deaths.csv')

# Select subset of columns with dtype=int (all death columns)
df = df.set_index(['Country/Region', 'Province/State']).select_dtypes(int)

# Plot the first 10 regions
df.head(10).T.plot()
```

[image: Covid-19 deaths plot]